# When a Parent has no child in a one to many relationship I get a non-object error when checking it

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a 'Parent' Table (server) and  a 'Child' Table (Server Status) the server status is connected to the server table via its id e.g. the servers `id` is the same as the `server_id` in the server status migration using a one to many relationship. What I am trying to do then is iterate through my list of servers and then display the status of the server, which is stores in the server status table. For some reason I am getting [non-object error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7PuI.png) when trying to iterate through a server that has no status. This works then a server has a status that is corresponding to it but but not when I have only a server and no status. Can anyone give me some insight on to why this may be happening? Here is the current code for the controller calling this view, and the loop used to iterate through the data.

index.blade.php:

```
@guest  
 @if(count($servers) > 0)
   @foreach($servers as $server)
     @if($server->isPublic === 1 )
        @include('inc.statuses')
     @endif
   @endforeach
 @endif
@endguest

@auth
 @if(count($servers) > 0)
   @foreach($servers as $server)
     @include('inc.statuses') 
   @endforeach
 @endif
@endauth
```

statuses.blade.php:

```
@if($server->serverStatus->last()->status_id === 1)
    <a href="/servers/{{$server->id}}"  class="text-dark list-group-item list-group-item-success">{{$server->name}}</a>
@elseif($server->serverStatus->last()->status_id === 2)
    <a href="/servers/{{$server->id}}" class="text-dark list-group-item list-group-item-warning" >{{$server->name}}</a>
@elseif($server->serverStatus->last()->status_id === 3)
    <a href="/servers/{{$server->id}}" class="text-dark list-group-item list-group-item-danger" >{{$server->name}}</a>
@elseif($server->serverStatus->last()->status_id === 4)
    <a href="/servers/{{$server->id}}" class="text-dark list-group-item list-group-item-warning" >{{$server->name}} is under maintinance</a>
@elseif($server->serverStatus->last()->status_id === null)
    <a href="/servers/{{$server->id}}" class="text-dark list-group-item list-group-item-warning" >{{$server->name}} has no inputted staus</a>
@else
    <a href="/servers/{{$server->id}}" class="text-dark list-group-item list-group-item-warning" >{{$server->name}} has no inputted staus</a>
@endif
```

controller:

```
public function index(){
        $servers = Server::orderBY('created_at', 'desc')->get();

        // foreach($servers as $server){
        //     var_dump($server->name);
        //     var_dump($server->serverStatus->last()->status_id);
        //     var_dump($server->serverStatus->last()->server_id);
        // }

        $incidents = Incident::orderBY('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);

        return view('pages.index', ['incidents' => $incidents, 'servers' => $servers]);
    }
```

Comment: !empty($server->serverStatus) add this condition as well in your blade file

Comment: Use `$servers = Server::has('serverStatus')->orderBY('created_at', 'desc')->get();` to get only servers with status.

Comment: @TheFallen worked like a charm, if you add it to an answer I will accept as soon as I can, i'm fairly new to laravel and forgot I could chain commands like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$servers = Server::has('serverStatus')->orderBY('created_at', 'desc')->get();` to get only servers with status.